# How can I customize the formatting of a ControlsFX autocomplete textbox?

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I have an autocomplete textbox:

```
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(txt_numberOfCard_GENERAL, PossibleWords);
```

How can I change the text size and color of the autocomplete drop-down list?